# Problem in Deleting Row from JTable And Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I Need to delete selected row from Jtable which connected to Mysql database

I successfully make another class to add book and it's work fine

i make this class to delete book added in the table , but i cannot find where the problem in my code , and i don't get any error

IDE : netBeans

here is the class code :

```
    package finallibrary;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class BookDetails extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;
    private JTextField search;
    private JButton b1, b2, b3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BookDetails().setVisible(true);
    }

    public void Book() {
        try {
            Conn con = new Conn();
            String sql = "select * from book";
            PreparedStatement st = con.c.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

            table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            rs.close();
            st.close();
            con.c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public BookDetails() {
        setTitle("Book List");
        setBounds(350, 200, 890, 475);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(36, 133, 802, 268);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                search.setText(table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
            }
        });
        table.setBackground(new Color(240, 248, 255));
        table.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        table.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 16));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Search");
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b1.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 18));
        b1.setBounds(564, 89, 108, 33);
        contentPane.add(b1);

        JButton b2 = new JButton("Delete");
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b2.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 18));
        b2.setBounds(712, 89, 108, 33);
        contentPane.add(b2);

        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Book Details");
        l1.setForeground(SystemColor.desktop);
        l1.setFont(new Font("Bookman Old Style", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        l1.setBounds(302, 11, 400, 47);
        contentPane.add(l1);

        search = new JTextField();
        search.setForeground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
        search.setFont(new Font("Book Antiqua", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        search.setBounds(189, 89, 357, 33);
        contentPane.add(search);
        search.setColumns(10);

        JButton b3 = new JButton("Back");
        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Home home = new Home();
                home.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        b3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                setVisible(false);
                Home home = new Home();
                home.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        b3.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 18));
        b3.setBounds(36, 89, 103, 33);
        contentPane.add(b3);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 128, 128), 3, true), "Book-Details",
                TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, new Color(0, 128, 0)));
        panel.setBounds(10, 52, 849, 373);
        contentPane.add(panel);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Book();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        
            
                
              try {

            Conn con = new Conn();
            if (ae.getSource() == b1) {

                String sql = "select * from book where concat(name, book_id) like ?";
                PreparedStatement st = con.c.prepareStatement(sql);
                st.setString(1, "%" + search.getText() + "%");
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                rs.close();
                st.close();

            }
            if (ae.getSource() == b2) {
                String sql = "delete from book where name = '" + search.getText() + "'";
                PreparedStatement st = con.c.prepareStatement(sql);

                JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to continue?", "Confirm",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {

                } else if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    int rs = st.executeUpdate();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deleted !!");
                } else if (response == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {

                }
                st.close();

            }

            con.c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                    
                    
                
                }
                
    }
}
```

Comment: The concrete `TableModel` returned by `DbUtils` may have a method to `removeRow()`.

Comment: 1) *"i don't get any error"* change every `catch (Exception e) {` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();` and you will. [Edit] to add it. 2) Use layouts to control the size and location of components.